# How to handle division of a very small numerator?

Tags: javascript, math, floating-point

I'm developing a JavaScript calculator and facing an issue with the division operation. When very small numerators are divided by large denominators, the result becomes "0". This isn't the desired behavior. Ideally, the calculator should either:

- Display a more informative message (e.g., "Number too small to divide").
- If possible, overcome this limitation and continue dividing.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Approaching Zero</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        const result = 1.2e-321 / 99999999999999;
        console.log(result);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I thought it would continue processing despite how small it is, but it turns out it's not enough for precision and accuracy.

Comment: yes, computers despite their name cannot compute very small or very large numbers, you need to use special libraries and/or approaches, related https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-can-i-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript

Comment: See also [Number.MIN_VALUE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/MIN_VALUE)

Comment: Furkan KARADENİZ, so with `some_non_zero_a/some_non_zero_b`, you want a quotient that is either a message or something that is not **ever** 0?

Comment: @Reinstate Monica  Yes, that's what I'm talking about. But from what I learn, it is a bit difficult to get something that is not ever 0 with vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

> Number too small to divide

Test the operands and quotient.

```js
const a = 1.2e-321;
const b = 99999999999999;
const result = a/b;

if (result === 0 && a !== 0) {
  console.log(`this cannot be evaluated`);
}
```

Comment: Actually, simple but great answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try somthing like that:

```js
function decomp(n) {
    let exp=0; 
    while(n<1|n>10){
        if(n<1){n*=10;exp++;}
        else if(n>10){n/=10;exp--;}
        else return [n, exp];
    }
    return [n, 0];

}
function division(n, d) {n=decomp(n);d=decomp(d);return [n[0]/d[0], n[1]-d[1]]}
```

It returns a table with two elements : `[n, exp]` in which `1<n<10` and the result of the division equals to `n*(10^exp)`.

The function `decomp` permits to transform a float into its scientific notation `[n, exp]`. This way, when you call `division(a,b)`, it divides 2 numbers that are greater than `1` and lower than `10`, and there is not any problem anymore with precision.

I hope that it is clearer and that it helps you.

Comment: I didn't understand much of the code due to my lack of knowledge, but I think this might be some sort of scientific notation? If it is, where can i learn about this logic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

as Iłya outlined in the comment, this issue comes from the fundamental flaw of JS handling binary floating-point operations. As outlined in the [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458633/how-can-i-deal-with-floating-point-number-precision-in-javascript).

If you want your calculations to be precise you can achieve it via a few ways:

- changing the datatype
- performing calculations with integers and accounting for decimals with precision

  - example: a user inputs 1, your internal code, would track the number as 1 * 10^36 (up to 36 decimal points)

Personally, I solved this issue with a use of an external JS library called [JS Big Decimal](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal). This would allow you to store numbers in string format and perform basic operations with them, like:

- addition,
- subtraction,
- multiplication,
- division,
- equation.

A few notes for the approach:

- This approach might not be optimal for database storage unless in specific cases, where precision is required over storage space.
- You would need to develop functions for more advanced options such as:

  - raising to the power
  - taking a root of a number

Comment: Thank you for sharing the library with me :)

Comment: I added a <script> tag for js-big-decimal in my HTML. It seems to be attached to the window object. However, when I try to use methods like bigDecimal.add("12", "45"), I get an error saying it's not a function. The same error occurs when I try to use the constructor itself.

Comment: @FurkanKARADENİZ Did you properly import the library to where you are using it in the file, via *require* from this example on the package page? https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-big-decimal#usage

Comment: Actually, I am implementing this with a script tag, as it will be executed on the browser side.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use extended precision libraries, you could instead switch to storing the log of the number instead of the number itself. This is okay for intermediate results, but won't allow you to print the number easily, without converting it back to normal representation, if it's in the range of the datatype. Multiplication and division of such logs is easy.

```
log2(a*b) = log2(a) + log2(b)

log2(a/b) = log2(a) - log2(b)
```

For example, if a = 1.2e-321 and b = 99999999999999, then

```
log2(a/b) = −1066.0758840530095 - 46.5069933284231 = −1112.5828773814326
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing your knowledge with me :)